What to do when you introduced breaking changes in a rest api, consequences were real and you found out about it after the fact?
I’m an external IT Consultant (a Java developer) working for a state-owned agency (the client) that deals with monthly payments (f.e. allowances, pensions etc). My team doesn’t maintain systems that deal with payments directly, instead we handle a sort of “customer data” that is used by the said payment systems.
Just before going on a long holiday, I did a change in the response of a REST API that was supposed to be used by Team A for a system for which the API was initially developed. This change made it to production, no regressions etc. Team A was aware, I presented my changes in a demo session, they adapted their system etc. I changed the response of the API because it contained some incorrect data and I removed this incorrect data directly, without providing a new version for the API.
But when I got back from my holiday and sieved through my e-mails I found out that another payment system that used this REST API (without my, or my team’s knowledge) couldn’t find the information it was supposed to find in the response of the updated API following my change, and hundreds of people who were expecting a payment, didn’t receive it anymore. In the meantime the Team B responsible for this other system adapted their code and these people will get their money eventually. When I resumed working nobody mentioned anything about this. They discovered this issue roughly one month after it was deployed in production, hence the hundreds of people impacted...
I realize now my mistakes. The most important one was not to introduce the changes as a new, separate API version, but directly. I was too confident in removing incorrect data, because I thought nobody was using it because it was incorrect to begin with. Equally important mistake was not to globally communicate on a global channel that there was going to be a change in this REST API. I didn’t deem it necessary because this API was designed for one project only, and I communicated and had demo session with them.
How should I handle this, in a professional manner, with our team’s Coordinator at the agency, the architect, my team’s lead analyst and my manager from the company with which I have the contract ? How should I take responsibility in a professional way ? Should I approach the coordinator and/or the architect (these are cross-team roles) first ? Or my team’s lead analyst first? Should I brush up my CV and start looking for a new job ?
This is what I did so far:
I apologized to Team B, in writing. I reviewed the changes I did, and the examples sent by the Team B, to see if they indeed used what seemed to be incorrect data in the first place. I reviewed the comments of the ticket and checked if there was any way for me to know, on my own, if other systems used this API.
Thanks!

"How should I handle this, in a professional manner, with our team’s Coordinator at the agency, the architect, my team’s lead analyst and my manager from the company with which I have the contract?" - You let notify your (manager, architect, and lead analyst) of the change and allow them to communicate the change to users of the API. Was it even your responsibility to notify the users?

Apart from the topic of apologizing, which is touched upon in the answer by @EdwinBock, the professional way to deal with this error is to tell your architect and lead analyst about what happened. This should not be in the form of an apology, but a fact-based narrative of a failure in the processes that are in place.
After having informed the technical leaders of this incident, you should start looking together (and maybe with the team as well) on how the processes can be improved so that a repeat of this incident can be avoided.

And if you read closely, my answer is about how you will likely not be empowered to apologize (which has to be defined first), because of corporate policies.  As a result, you MUST go with a "fact based narrative of (the) failure) and the processes in place" with a plan to alter the processes (after that plan is improved) to ensure it doesn't happen again.

The other answers are good but are missing an additional two items:

Don't push out updates right before holidays
Don't push out updates right before vacations

At my company we follow the standards, including communications, versioning, testings, etc. But we know that sometimes stuff happens. We are people.

We don't push out updates on Fridays (We like our weekends).
We don't push out updates for 2 weeks prior to the product lead's vacation.

After 40 years, it is starting to sink in - we don't have to be our own worst enemy.

"we don't have to be our own worst enemy." this 1000%.  There are plenty of actors in the system that can cause trouble, don't be doing it to yourself.

The OP mentioned that the issue was detected about 1 month after the update going live. I guess it was either a long holiday or the update went live a bit longer before the holiday started.

@BartvanIngenSchenau  The OP's words "Just before going on a long holiday, I did a change in the response of a REST API". Sounds European for vacation :) But that is case in point why we don't push out changes 2 weeks before product lead goes on vacation (or holiday for those on the other side of the pond).

@DogBoy37, Also the OP's words (end of third paragraph) "They discovered this issue roughly one month after it was deployed in production". The 'not on Friday' rule I can understand (for a public-facing service), but the '2 weeks prior to vacation' rule I find a bit arbitrary. But we can agree to disagree on that one.

You apologize, but not all apologies are equal.  Good apologies include:

A sincere expression that you are sorry.
You take responsibility for the act.
Your plan to make amends for the hurt.
Showing appreciation of the other person, not apologizing out of obligation.
Listening to their complaints without minimizing them.
Committing to doing better next time.

Think before you speak, time your apology appropriately.
Now, in a business setting, there's a lot of problems with a good apology, and this makes apologizing much more difficult

A culture of "nothing should go wrong" exists.  If this culture is violated, a scapegoat "the person that did wrong" should be blamed and punished.
A chance (or certainty) of a lawsuit has companies and organizations act to protect themselves even when they are in the wrong.  As a result, your legal team may see an apology as giving proof of the hurt that can later be used in legal settings.
These two items combine to create scenarios where those that generally attempt to protect against problems are the ones that get blamed.  Their protections are deemed "not enough" and the deeper issues of "lack of a proper testing plan" and "lack of ability to mitigate issues in production" which are typically handled by upper layers of management calling for them, are ignored.

I will guess that you are in a typical USA corporation, or one that interacts with a typical USA corporation.  If so, odds are they will want you to NOT apologize, for reasons like:

The amount of money involved makes the risks seem too great
Corporate legals teams require a policy of never apologizing as a future lawsuit prevention tactic.
The corporation has a culture of "always right" and "never having a problem" as the status quo.  Violations of that culture are deemed irreprehensible.
Those in power think the risk of a lawsuit will pass more quickly if the idea of wrong is glossed over by not offering an apology.

If any of the above (or more) apply, odds are you are not enabled to give an apology.  When such a scenario exists, the only things you can do is

Suggest to upper management for a corporate apology.
Be as cooperative with your team and the people you impacted in repairing the issues.
Once the matter is fully resolved, nearly forgotten, and out of legal risk, you might be able to offer a belated apology.  This is not "after it is fixed" this is long after the fact, when nobody's upset and the losses are forgotten.

I know you feel bad about what has happened, but the best course of action at this time is to do nothing outside of your immediate management.  Let your manager know that you feel bad about the impacts, and present him with a plan to ensure that such a thing never happens again.
As you already communicated to "team B" there is a chance that you did more damage than you think (depending on who "team B" is, and how the company works).  The best policy here is to shift from the mistake to advertisement of how the "new approach" that you will promote in your team's retrospective will prevent such a thing from ever happening again (putting documentation tasks into the sprint, tying the release build to release notes containing API changes, etc.)

Appreciate your input.
I think that I did apologize sincerely to Team B (a team not unlike ours, in the same agency) for the issue and extra work to correct it, recognizing my mistakes, but without saying what those mistakes were, instead mentioning what I will do in the future to prevent this.
Apparently this is not what I should have done, if I understand you answer correctly.
The state-owned agency that I'm working for is in Europe. It never crossed my mind that there's a chance for a lawsuit though. Now I'm worried.

So a key takeaway from your answer is that there could be a corporate policy that deals with how mistakes should be acknowledged or not.

@user27021198 The best thing to do is to start forgetting about what happened, except in the context of how to prevent it from happening again.  Not repeating the same mistakes is one of the most direct ways to show an apology is sincere, and can be done even without the words of apology.  Note that lawyers are creative and fearful people, constantly fighting in their minds so you won't have to in court.  Humans tend to be a little more forgiving, and odds are that not much will come out of it, if the person on the other end recognizes that they could have done the same thing.


I didn’t deem it necessary because this API was designed for one project only, and I communicated and had demo session with them.
How should I handle this

It doesn't sound like something that needs a massive apology, just a perfunctory one perhaps, unless you know you took a shortcut from ordinary standards.
There can be room for improvement without there always being wrongdoing.
A written explanation of the cause, and am acknowledgement of the role you played in it, seems enough.
The purpose of this is so that people have an idea to learn how things go wrong and have a chance of pre-empting it in future.
It doesn't sound like a resigning matter.

Thanks! After I sent the apology e-mail, I got a reply from & discussed with the developer who discovered the issue. In his original e-mail he agreed that they used data from a "convenient" place (rather than, I would say, from a "correct" place).
He was relaxed and downplayed the problem. He sees it as a "company concern", not a "personal" one because of late discovery - no sys failed. He understood why I did the change, and acknowledged it simplifies some workaround that they had to do. I think he was sincere when he told me that he thinks the coordinators probably already forgot about it.
